# Make active menu marker slide when hover and click using pure css?

Tags: html, css

I have a marker created with pseudo element. I'm trying to use `transitions`
 to achieve a sliding effect but no success at all... I've been looking for a solution for almost a day.. your help will be much appreciated.
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mh0qw9fL/).

I added a jquery just to move the active link but my actual codes doesn't use jquery at all. Maybe there's a way to achieve the sliding effect using pure css.

Comment: The current set-up won't work because the red 'marker' is relative to each parent element (in your case li.active). Animation only works on the same element and/or child elements of that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a good start up: [FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/b05bg77j)

pure css `javalamp`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to make with transitions only. You have multiple li's and each of them has one :before element. By clicking on them you just turn those elements on/off (it could have fade effect). 
What you need is only one border (span or whatever) and when you click on li's it will move that border under it. It can be easily done with jQuery (for example when you click on the third li, span will move left -> li.first width + li.second width + margins if any). I don't think this could be done with css only.

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mh0qw9fL/2/) I created function:

```
animateBorder();
```

And to make it more interesting: [JSFIDDLE - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mh0qw9fL/3/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try jquery if you can suggest a code.